# ActionScript Error: 1120: Access of undefined property myRec on a defined variable

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I'm trying to write a dollar recognizer in Flash Builder. I'm really new to actionscript and mxml, and I''m getting this error on the line "myRec.addTemplate..." in the code below:

```
import de.yuv.gestures.Recognizer;

import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;

var myRec:Recognizer = new Recognizer();

myRec.addTemplate("triangle", new Array(new Point(137,139),new Point(135,141),new Point(133,144),new Point(132,146),new Point(130,149),new Point(128,151),new Point(126,155),new Point(123,160),new Point(120,166),new Point(116,171),new Point(112,177),new Point(107,183),new Point(102,188),new Point(100,191),new Point(95,195),new Point(90,199),new Point(86,203),new Point(82,206),new Point(80,209),new Point(75,213),new Point(73,213),new Point(70,216),new Point(67,219),new Point(64,221),new Point(61,223),new Point(60,225),new Point(62,226),new Point(65,225),new Point(67,226),new Point(74,226),new Point(77,227),new Point(85,229),new Point(91,230),new Point(99,231),new Point(108,232),new Point(116,233),new Point(125,233),new Point(134,234),new Point(145,233),new Point(153,232),new Point(160,233),new Point(170,234),new Point(177,235),new Point(179,236),new Point(186,237),new Point(193,238),new Point(198,239),new Point(200,237),new Point(202,239),new Point(204,238),new Point(206,234),new Point(205,230),new Point(202,222),new Point(197,216),new Point(192,207),new Point(186,198),new Point(179,189),new Point(174,183),new Point(170,178),new Point(164,171),new Point(161,168),new Point(154,160),new Point(148,155),new Point(143,150),new Point(138,148),new Point(136,148)));
```

It's really confusing me since I've defined myRec just above it. The same code, though, works in Flash Professional, which leads me to believe that I'm missing some import statement or other subtlety that isn't being made clear my this error message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
NinjaSteph

Edit (complete error message):
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
1120: Access of undefined property myRec.   GestureRecognizer.mxml  /GestureRecognizer/src  line 17 Flex Problem

Edit (complete mxml file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" currentState="Title">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import de.yuv.gestures.Recognizer;

    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    var myRec:Recognizer = new Recognizer();

    myRec.addTemplate("triangle", new Array(new Point(137,139),new Point(135,141),new Point(133,144),new Point(132,146),new Point(130,149),new Point(128,151),new Point(126,155),new Point(123,160),new Point(120,166),new Point(116,171),new Point(112,177),new Point(107,183),new Point(102,188),new Point(100,191),new Point(95,195),new Point(90,199),new Point(86,203),new Point(82,206),new Point(80,209),new Point(75,213),new Point(73,213),new Point(70,216),new Point(67,219),new Point(64,221),new Point(61,223),new Point(60,225),new Point(62,226),new Point(65,225),new Point(67,226),new Point(74,226),new Point(77,227),new Point(85,229),new Point(91,230),new Point(99,231),new Point(108,232),new Point(116,233),new Point(125,233),new Point(134,234),new Point(145,233),new Point(153,232),new Point(160,233),new Point(170,234),new Point(177,235),new Point(179,236),new Point(186,237),new Point(193,238),new Point(198,239),new Point(200,237),new Point(202,239),new Point(204,238),new Point(206,234),new Point(205,230),new Point(202,222),new Point(197,216),new Point(192,207),new Point(186,198),new Point(179,189),new Point(174,183),new Point(170,178),new Point(164,171),new Point(161,168),new Point(154,160),new Point(148,155),new Point(143,150),new Point(138,148),new Point(136,148)));

    var recordedPoints:Array;
    public function hideAllHighlights():void
    {
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < myRec.Templates.length; i++){

            var mc:MovieClip = this["mc_"+myRec.Templates[i].Name];
            trace(mc);
            if (mc)
            {
                mc.visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    var record:Boolean = false;

    //hideAllHighlights();

    public function handleMouseDown (event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace('handleMouseDown:');
        record = true;
        hideAllHighlights();
        recordedPoints = new Array();
        //clear objects from stage that are not circles
        for(var i:int = 0; recPanel.stage.numChildren>i; ){
            if(recPanel.stage.getChildAt(i).name == "circle")
                recPanel.stage.removeChildAt(i);
            else
                i++;
        }
    }

    public function handleMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace('handleMouseUp:');
        record = false;
        var myResult = myRec.recognize(recordedPoints);
        trace (myResult.Name);
        trace (myResult.Score);
        resLabel.text = myResult.Name;
        /*var mc:MovieClip = this["mc_"+myResult.Name];
        if (mc){
            mc.visible = true;
        }*/ 
    }

    public function drawCircle(x:Number, y:Number):void
    {
        var circle:Shape = new Shape;
        circle.name = "circle";
        var radius:Number = 1;
        circle.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        circle.graphics.drawCircle(x+recPanel.x, y+recPanel.y, radius);
        recPanel.stage.addChild(circle);
    }

    public function handleMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (record){
            trace('handleMouseMove'+event.localX+" "+event.localY);
            recordedPoints.push(new Point(event.localX,event.localY));
            drawCircle(event.localX,event.localY);
        }
    }

    //recPanel.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleMouseDown );
    //recPanel.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouseUp );
    //recPanel.addEventListener ( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove );

    protected function startBkgd_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        setCurrentState("RecognizerState");
    }

]]></fx:Script>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="Title"/>
    <s:State name="RecognizerState"/>
</s:states>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label includeIn="Title" fontSize="36" horizontalCenter="0" text="Dollar Gesture Recognizer"
         textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" verticalCenter="-30"/>
<s:Label includeIn="Title" fontSize="18" horizontalCenter="0" text=""
         verticalCenter="40"/>
<s:Panel id="recPanel" includeIn="RecognizerState" left="50" width="400" height="400"
         color="#0B333C" fontSize="24" textAlign="center" title="Gesture Recognizer"
         verticalCenter="0" mouseDown="handleMouseDown(event)" mouseMove="handleMouseMove(event)"
         mouseUp="handleMouseUp(event)">
</s:Panel>
<s:Panel id="gesPanel" includeIn="RecognizerState" width="300" height="400" fontSize="24"
         horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="center" title="Available Gestures" verticalCenter="0">
</s:Panel>
<s:Label id="startBkgd" includeIn="Title" x="10" y="10" width="1263" height="591"
         click="startBkgd_clickHandler(event)" />
<s:Panel id="resMeme" includeIn="RecognizerState" right="50" width="400" height="400"
         fontSize="24" title="Resulting Meme" verticalCenter="0">
    <s:Label id="resLabel" x="103" y="165" width="180" text="result" textAlign="center"/>
</s:Panel>
```

Recognizer class:

```
package de.yuv.gestures
{
import de.yuv.gestures.Result;
import de.yuv.gestures.Template;

import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
public class Recognizer {

    public static var NumPoints:int = 64;


    public static var SquareSize:Number = 250.0;
    public static var HalfDiagonal = 0.5 * Math.sqrt(250.0 * 250.0 + 250.0 * 250.0);
    public static var AngleRange = 45.0;
    public static var AnglePrecision = 2.0;
    public static var Phi = 0.5 * (-1.0 + Math.sqrt(5.0)); // Golden Ratio
    public var Templates:Array;


    public function Recognizer(){
            this.Templates = new Array();
    }

    public function recognize(points)
    {
        points = Resample(points, NumPoints);
        points = RotateToZero(points);
        points = ScaleToSquare(points, SquareSize);
        points = TranslateToOrigin(points);

        var b = +Infinity;
        var t;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.Templates.length; i++)
        {
            var d = DistanceAtBestAngle(points, this.Templates[i], -AngleRange, +AngleRange, AnglePrecision);
            if (d < b)
            {
                b = d;
                t = i;
            }
        }
        var score = 1.0 - (b / HalfDiagonal);
        return new Result(this.Templates[t].Name, score);
    };
    //
    // add/delete new templates
    //
    public function addTemplate(name, points)
    {
        this.Templates[this.Templates.length] = new Template(name, points); // append new template
        var num = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.Templates.length; i++)
        {
            if (this.Templates[i].Name == name)
                num++;
        }
        return num;
    }


    // Helper functions

    public static function Resample(points, n)
    {
        var I = PathLength(points) / (n - 1); // interval length
        var D = 0.0;
        var newpoints = new Array(points[0]);
        for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++)
        {
            var d = Distance(points[i - 1], points[i]);
            if ((D + d) >= I)
            {
                var qx = points[i - 1].x + ((I - D) / d) * (points[i].x - points[i - 1].x);
                var qy = points[i - 1].y + ((I - D) / d) * (points[i].y - points[i - 1].y);
                var q = new Point(qx, qy);
                newpoints[newpoints.length] = q; // append new point 'q'
                points.splice(i, 0, q); // insert 'q' at position i in points s.t. 'q' will be the next i
                D = 0.0;
            }
            else D += d;
        }
        // somtimes we fall a rounding-error short of adding the last point, so add it if so
        if (newpoints.length == n - 1)
        {
            newpoints[newpoints.length] = points[points.length - 1];
        }
        return newpoints;
    }
    public static function RotateToZero(points)
    {
        var c = Centroid(points);
        var theta = Math.atan2(c.y - points[0].y, c.x - points[0].x);
        return RotateBy(points, -theta);
    }

    public static function ScaleToSquare(points, size)
    {
        var B = BoundingBox(points);
        var newpoints = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
        {
            var qx = points[i].x * (size / B.width);
            var qy = points[i].y * (size / B.height);
            newpoints[newpoints.length] = new Point(qx, qy);
        }
        return newpoints;
    }           
    public static function TranslateToOrigin(points)
    {
        var c = Centroid(points);
        var newpoints = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
        {
            var qx = points[i].x - c.x;
            var qy = points[i].y - c.y;
            newpoints[newpoints.length] = new Point(qx, qy);
        }
        return newpoints;
    }

    public static function DistanceAtBestAngle(points, T, a, b, threshold)
    {
        var x1 = Phi * a + (1.0 - Phi) * b;
        var f1 = DistanceAtAngle(points, T, x1);
        var x2 = (1.0 - Phi) * a + Phi * b;
        var f2 = DistanceAtAngle(points, T, x2);
        while (Math.abs(b - a) > threshold)
        {
            if (f1 < f2)
            {
                b = x2;
                x2 = x1;
                f2 = f1;
                x1 = Phi * a + (1.0 - Phi) * b;
                f1 = DistanceAtAngle(points, T, x1);
            }
            else
            {
                a = x1;
                x1 = x2;
                f1 = f2;
                x2 = (1.0 - Phi) * a + Phi * b;
                f2 = DistanceAtAngle(points, T, x2);
            }
        }
        return Math.min(f1, f2);
    }

    public static function PathLength(points)
    {
        var d = 0.0;
        for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++)
            d += Distance(points[i - 1], points[i]);
        return d;
    }

    public static function Distance(p1, p2)
    {
        var dx = p2.x - p1.x;
        var dy = p2.y - p1.y;
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }
    public static function Centroid(points)
    {
        var x = 0.0, y = 0.0;
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
        {
            x += points[i].x;
            y += points[i].y;
        }
        x /= points.length;
        y /= points.length;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
    public static function RotateBy(points, theta) 
    {
        var c = Centroid(points);
        var cos = Math.cos(theta);
        var sin = Math.sin(theta);

        var newpoints = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
        {
            var qx = (points[i].x - c.x) * cos - (points[i].y - c.y) * sin + c.x
            var qy = (points[i].x - c.x) * sin + (points[i].y - c.y) * cos + c.y;
            newpoints[newpoints.length] = new Point(qx, qy);
        }
        return newpoints;
    }
    public static function BoundingBox(points)
    {
        var minX = +Infinity, maxX = -Infinity, minY = +Infinity, maxY = -Infinity;
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
        {
            if (points[i].x < minX)
                minX = points[i].x;
            if (points[i].x > maxX)
                maxX = points[i].x;
            if (points[i].y < minY)
                minY = points[i].y;
            if (points[i].y > maxY)
                maxY = points[i].y;
        }
        return new Rectangle(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
    }

    public static function DistanceAtAngle(points, T, theta)
    {
        var newpoints = RotateBy(points, theta);
        return PathDistance(newpoints, T.Points);
    }

    public static function PathDistance(pts1, pts2)
    {
        var d = 0.0;
        for (var i = 0; i < pts1.length; i++) // assumes pts1.length == pts2.length
            d += Distance(pts1[i], pts2[i]);
        return d / pts1.length;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is this contained? A mxml file? Show it please.

Comment: I have a real suspicion that you haven't posted the correct error code. I think you typed it out paraphrasing it. Recompile your code and this time copy and paste the exact error message from the compiler output verbatim.

Comment: Since I cannot actually answer this yet, I will include my answer here. I put the offending line of code inside a function that I run at the start of my application and that worked. I guess I was just missing something very fundamental about actionscript.

Here's the code for my fix:

`var myRec:Recognizer = new Recognizer();
    public function start():void
    {
 myRec.addTemplate("triangle", new Array(new Point(137,139),new Point(135,141)...));
    }`

Comment: @NinjaSteph you should be able to answer the question, please post the answer under the answers section.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this be in some sort of class?

as in:

```
package
{
    // imports

    public class Main() extends Sprite // extend Sprite if you want to use it as your document class
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            // your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for a guess and a bad one at that. If that class structure were important we'd have a different type of error. No class where it should be has little to no bearing as to why the code compiles yet an object remains undefined.

Comment: My reputation is to low to +1 this, but his post ended up helping me out. More details are in my answer.

Comment: I up voted this, since it's obvious that the reason this is failing is because the code throwing the error is floating around "loose", rather than being inside a method. The offending code belongs to the Class definition rather than the instance (which is what would need to "own" that code to be able to see the assignment).

Answer (score 0):

@Amy Blackenship, you are right as I was leaving my code "loose" within my script. Instead of creating a needless class though, I simply put the code within a function that I run when my application starts and that worked. I seems I was just missing something very fundamental about actionscript.

Here's the code for my fix:

```
    var myRec:Recognizer = new Recognizer();
    public function start():void
    {
        //resImage.source = "assets/omeme.jpg";
        myRec.addTemplate("triangle", new Array(new Point(137,139),new Point(135,141),new Point(133,144),new Point(132,146),new Point(130,149),new Point(128,151),new Point(126,155),new Point(123,160),new Point(120,166),new Point(116,171),new Point(112,177),new Point(107,183),new Point(102,188),new Point(100,191),new Point(95,195),new Point(90,199),new Point(86,203),new Point(82,206),new Point(80,209),new Point(75,213),new Point(73,213),new Point(70,216),new Point(67,219),new Point(64,221),new Point(61,223),new Point(60,225),new Point(62,226),new Point(65,225),new Point(67,226),new Point(74,226),new Point(77,227),new Point(85,229),new Point(91,230),new Point(99,231),new Point(108,232),new Point(116,233),new Point(125,233),new Point(134,234),new Point(145,233),new Point(153,232),new Point(160,233),new Point(170,234),new Point(177,235),new Point(179,236),new Point(186,237),new Point(193,238),new Point(198,239),new Point(200,237),new Point(202,239),new Point(204,238),new Point(206,234),new Point(205,230),new Point(202,222),new Point(197,216),new Point(192,207),new Point(186,198),new Point(179,189),new Point(174,183),new Point(170,178),new Point(164,171),new Point(161,168),new Point(154,160),new Point(148,155),new Point(143,150),new Point(138,148),new Point(136,148)));
```

Thanks,

NinjaSteph